# An unexpected appearance

Tags: lateral-thinking, word-problem

Sandra walked to dinner alone one night. She had a lovely meal at a restaurant. No one else talked to her and she sat on her own table. At the end of the meal, she asked the waitress for the bill and suddenly George, Thomas and Ben showed up to pay for the meal. They did not speak to Sandra at all and didn't feel any emotions toward her. As soon as the bill was paid, they abandoned Sandra and left with another woman. Sandra left the restaurant alone and walked back to her home.

Sandra considered this a very normal night. How can you explain what happened?

Comment: Sorry, -1: nothing in this question hints at its geographically localised nature. Not everyone on this site knows even the first thing about US currency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> George, Thomas and Ben represent american currency. George Washington on the 1 dollar bill, Thomas Jefferson on the nickel, and Ben Franklin on the 100 dollar bill. She used them to pay her bill to the waitress and then left

Comment: Correct! Very quickly answered aswell.

Comment: Ben Franklin is on the 100 dollar bill.  Abraham Lincoln is on the 5 dollar bill.

Comment: Ahh yup, not quite sure what I was thinking there.  Fixed, thanks